# Find font-family of the html element on which mouse is currently pointing?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to find out font family of the HTML element on which my mouse is hovering. Please do not suggest a Chrome/FF plugin for this, I want to create one myself :P

Here is what I have been trying: http://jsfiddle.net/c2DUZ/

Html :

```
<div id="a">hasdashd kjsa sdkjsahd kjahdkjsahd kjahdkjahd kja hdkja hdkjahdskjahdkja</div>
<div id="b">hasdashd kjsa sdkjsahd kjahdkjsahd kjahdkjahd kja hdkja hdkjahdskjahdkja</div>
<div id="c">hasdashd kjsa sdkjsahd kjahdkjsahd kjahdkjahd kja hdkja hdkjahdskjahdkja</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Css:

```
#a {font-family: Arial;}
#b {font-family: Tahoma;}
#c {font-family: Georgia;}
```

Jquery

```
$('*').hover(function() {
    hoverElem = this
    var font = hoverElem.css("font-family");
    $("#message").append(font);
});
```

Please advice.

Comment: As a good advice, press F12...

Comment: LOL @A.Wolff I was doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your JS thus:

`hoverElem = $(this);`

In order to ensure you are referencing a jQuery object and have access to the CSS method

Answer (score 0):

Although SW4 has answered, I would like to give more explanation.

You can use jquery functions only if they are a jquery object.

In your current code, `this` refers to a `HTMLELement`.

You can make any DOM element as if it was a jquery object by wrapping it with `$( )`.

So `hoverElem = $(this);` will make hoverElem a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way as you want it in jQuery.

```
$('#selector').css('font-family');
```